# Webpack optimize-minimize breaks gradients in Firefox?

Tags: css, sass, webpack, css-loader

I have a [simple landing page](http://coin-garden.com/) and I used webpack. If I run webpack with `-p` flag which stands for `-optimize-minimize` it will break css gradients in Firefox. Instead of smooth color change I see harsh stripes.

Under the hood css-loader using cssnano module.

Any idea what causing this issue?

Thanks,

```
{
      test: /.scss$/i,
      loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap&safe', 'postcss-loader', 'sass?sourceMap'],
}
```

Comment: No idea but have you tried using `autoprefixer-loader` before `sass-loader`?

Comment: @ArchNoob yes, I use autoprefixer via postcss-loader. It's just weird that minified version of bundle breaks css

Comment: aha okay. Also i checked the output of my `css-gradients` there was only `webkit-linear-gradient` so i guess it doesn't apply. Maybe you could share your code somewhere so we can play around with it.

Comment: @ArchNoob yes absolutely, the code is available here https://github.com/vladmiller/coin-garden-landing-page not my best, was in hurry :D I also noticed that all other prefixes are missing, it feels like somehow cssnano removes css rules with the same name

Comment: I'm taking a look at it. I've seen the errors in firefox already and i see `container .section.section-welcome` is the one with gradient issues. I'm only giving you this comment to let you know i'm looking at it :) .

Comment: @ArchNoob actually there are two containers with gradient issues, body and section-welcome :) I'm also still trying my luck to find issue